Symmetry breaking/Phase transitions
I have completly edited the question to focus on one problem.
I have seen on different places that it is claimed that the inflation was triggered by a phase transition/symmetry breaking of strong force unification(see here below the inflation title:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang.).
As we know that the statndard inflation scenarios are based on a classical scalar field with a potential in a slow roll inflation.
My question is why on wikipedia they mentioned about a phase transition which caused the inflation instead of the standard scenario? Is there any standard inflation model which is based of symmetry breaking and they wrote with respect to it?

No abusive comments and links please

A nice reference on the connection between phase transitions and condensed matter physics in general to high energy physics is the book "Quantum Field Theory and Critical Phenomena" by Jean Zinn-Justin. There you might find some of the information youre looking for

In Guth's original, groundbreaking paper on inflation, he proposes spontaneous symmetry breaking as a mechanism for ending inflation, although he also in the same paper points out that this mechanism doesn't work :) https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevD.23.347

@Andrew as you said, there are problems in Guth's scenario, so it cant be considered "standard scenario".

I mean, if your question is, "why did someone on wikipedia write this sentence," that's not really a physics question. You're right on the physics. The Guth article I mentioned was just for context for why people might associate phase transitions with inflation.

@Andrew yep i know that sometimes we can find "loop-holes" on wikipedia. And if there any other reference then you can mention it here.
